# Attach result two select queries with different columns (Show one output)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two queries of `SQL SERVER` database and i want to join result of both queries,both queries show result.Is `union` or any thing help?But union merge all the record not shows both queries columns.

My queries:

```
 Select INITEMS.ITEMNO,
   MAX(INITEMS.ITEMDESC#1) AS 'ITEMDESC',
   SUM(INITEMS.QTY) 'Item Sale',
   CONVERT(date, MAX(HDR.DATE)) as 'Last sale date'
   FROM   InvItems INITEMS
   INNER JOIN InvHdr HDR ON  HDR.INVNO=INITEMS.INVNO 
   WHERE INITEMS.TYPE = '3'
   GROUP BY INITEMS.ITEMNO 

   Select WRK.ITEMEMPNO,
   MAX(ITEMS.ITEMDESC#1) AS 'ITEMDESC',
   SUM(WRK.QTY) 'Item Sale',
   CONVERT(date, MAX(WRK.DATE)) as 'Last Use date'
   FROM   WRKTRANS WRK
   INNER JOIN InvItems ITEMS ON  WRK.ITEMEMPNO=ITEMS.ITEMNO
   WHERE WRK.TYPE=1 AND WRK.STATUS=1 AND WRK.ISSUED=1 AND WRK.RECHARGE=0 AND 
    ITEMS.TYPE='3'
   GROUP BY WRK.ITEMEMPNO
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the desired output.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected result. You don't want to use a merge, you need to join the tables based on a related column between them

Comment: I want to use merge result,,show two queries result,union?

Comment: What do you mean "join". `JOIN` and `UNION` are very different operators

Comment: @Heinzi total i want 8 columns display in result, 4 columns from query 1 and 4 columns from query 2

Comment: @Larnu simple i want to union of two result,show two result,total i want 8 columns,4 column from query1 and 4 columns from query 2

Comment: Do you want to put columns side by side, or get all rows as a single set of rows?

Comment: Please don't use the words "Union" and "join" interchangeably; they have very distinct meaning the SQL Server. Saying you want to "union" the results into 8 columns from 4 isn't a `UNION` that's a `JOIN`. We still need that Sample data and expect results though.

Comment: @Larnu sorry ,this is very simple.I want result of 2 queries ,may b `union` is used,I want output like this,columns are `ITEMNO,ITEMDESC,Item Sale,Last sale date,ITEMNO,ITEMDESC,Item Sale,Last Use date` Two queries result in one output,hope you got it

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use a `UNION` then you could do something like this?

```
SELECT 
    i.ITEMNO,
    MAX(i.ITEMDESC#1) AS ITEMDESC,
    SUM(i.QTY) AS 'Item Sale',
    'Last sale date' AS DateText,
    CONVERT(DATE, MAX(HDR.DATE)) AS MyDate
FROM   
    InvItems i
    INNER JOIN InvHdr HDR ON  HDR.INVNO=INITEMS.INVNO 
WHERE 
    i.TYPE = '3'
GROUP BY 
    i.ITEMNO 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    WRK.ITEMEMPNO,
    MAX(ITEMS.ITEMDESC#1) AS ITEMDESC,
    SUM(WRK.QTY) AS 'Item Sale',
    'Last Use date' AS DateText,
    CONVERT(DATE, MAX(WRK.DATE)) AS MyDate
FROM   
    WRKTRANS WRK
    INNER JOIN InvItems ITEMS ON  WRK.ITEMEMPNO=ITEMS.ITEMNO
WHERE 
    WRK.TYPE=1 
    AND WRK.STATUS=1 
    AND WRK.ISSUED=1 
    AND WRK.RECHARGE=0 
    AND ITEMS.TYPE='3'
GROUP BY 
    WRK.ITEMEMPNO;
```

---

Or, for an "8-column mess" you *could* do something like this:

```
SELECT 
    i.ITEMNO,
    MAX(i.ITEMDESC#1) AS ITEMDESC AS ITEMDESC_1,
    SUM(i.QTY) AS 'Item Sale_1',
    CONVERT(DATE, MAX(HDR.DATE)) AS 'Last sale date',
    NULL AS ITEMPNO,
    NULL AS ITEMDESC_2,
    NULL AS 'Item Sale_2',
    NULL AS 'Last Use Date'
FROM   
    InvItems i
    INNER JOIN InvHdr HDR ON  HDR.INVNO=INITEMS.INVNO 
WHERE 
    i.TYPE = '3'
GROUP BY 
    i.ITEMNO 
UNION ALL
SELECT
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    WRK.ITEMEMPNO,
    MAX(ITEMS.ITEMDESC#1) AS ITEMDESC_2,
    SUM(WRK.QTY) AS 'Item Sale_2',
    CONVERT(DATE, MAX(WRK.DATE)) AS 'Last Use date'
FROM   
    WRKTRANS WRK
    INNER JOIN InvItems ITEMS ON  WRK.ITEMEMPNO=ITEMS.ITEMNO
WHERE 
    WRK.TYPE=1 
    AND WRK.STATUS=1 
    AND WRK.ISSUED=1 
    AND WRK.RECHARGE=0 
    AND ITEMS.TYPE='3'
GROUP BY 
    WRK.ITEMEMPNO;
```

Comment: sorry no i don't want this,this is very simple.I want result of 2 queries ,may b `union` is used,I want output like this,columns are `ITEMNO,ITEMDESC,Item Sale,Last sale date,ITEMNO,ITEMDESC,Item Sale,Last Use date` Two queries result in one output,hope you got it

Comment: Yes, that's what my second query attempts to do.  It will look a mess because you will have missing data where there's only data from one original query.